# Use EF Core as scoped service from within parallel executing actionblocks

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I want to use TPL DataFlow to execute some complex validation rules and transformations on multiple items with a degree of parallelism greater than 1. In certain occasions, the code needs to access the database through an EF Core datacontext which is registered in the application as a scoped service.

It is known that the degree of parallelism for a single dbcontext instance is 1 (you can execute at most 1 action on an EF Core dbcontext instance at a time, no matter what thread this action takes place).

My code starts to execute from a controller action. There I create the pipeline, feed the data in and await at the final target to complete (so the whole processing will complete during a web request). But individual item processing may be processed in parallel.

So when I create my dataflow pipeline, how can my code in the action blocks ensure that calls to the scoped dbcontext will be scheduled to execute sequentially?

Comment: Consider injecting a DbContextFactory and letting the parallel tasks scope their own instances of the DbContext provided these operations can run in parallel without any dependence on a sequence. Otherwise I'd reconsider performing parallel operations.

Comment: @StevePy I am thinking maybe I need to preload any data I may need (possibly using additional caching) and provide those data to the tasks. The data will be read-only once loaded. That way I won't need to access the DB from within the task items. The only problem I see, is which data I need to preload, since that depends on the data processed by the task items.

Comment: Don't use a DbContext or any other ORM. A DbContext isn't a database connection, it's a Unit-of-Work. In an ETL job there are on Objects to Map anyway, only rows, columns and values. Parallelism won't fix the fundamental problem in the architecture, it will only make it worse

Comment: Instead, use SqlBulkCopy or any other bulk copy mechanism offered by your database to insert data into a database in the fastest possible way. You can use FastMember's ObjectReader to create an IDbDataReader wrapper over any collection of objects to use them with SqlBulkCopy. TPL Dataflow can be used to transform or batch DTOs in your job so the final ActionBlock can insert them one batch at a time to the database

Comment: If you need to read data from the database, it's better to use Dapper or even straight ADO.NET to load just the data you want and preferably, store them in dictionaries to avoid hitting the database for every single lookup

Comment: PS: Chatzipavlis would freak if he read this

Comment: You really need to explain what you want to do. I've used Dataflow for complex ETL pipelines, never with EF Core. Things from parsing hundreds of CSVs in nested folders to import into a database, to calling web services to get a list of IDs, then call other services to get individual items, parse them and insert them in a database with various DOPs. The last step is a bulk insert into a staging table, not an attempt to modify 10K rows one by one. Batching and bulk operations are orders of magnitude faster than the Row By Row operations of an ORM. Bulk inserts are far faster than even batched

Comment: You could use EF Core without causing extreme delays if eg you had a small amount of data with objects in graphs and wanted to persist the graphs. You'd still have to use a separate Unit-of-Work ie DbContext for each operation, but by attaching the objects in the correct state you could avoid having to load them from database. But, that will always be a lot slower than bulk inserts

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos EFCore is used only for reading data in my case. As you pointed out the final insert will indeed happen at the end in a single bulk operation. What I want to do is import data from excel files then run business validation on each row. Business validation is complex and CPU bound and surely parallelism has a positive impact. Access to database data is needed only for lookup values so I resorted in creating dictionaries at the beginning before I push the first item in the dataflow pipeline.

Comment: If you use Excel how is EF involved? I process a ton of Excel files as well, using ExcelDataReader. The first block is a crawler that searches for files in a folder, second a TransformManyBlock that uses ExcelDataReader to extract the rows and emit them, appending the filename and row to each record, third a processing TransformBlock, then a BatchBlock to create batches of eg 1000 items and finally an ActionBlock with SqlBulkCopy. If I had to load data from a DB I'd use Dapper because ETL doesn't need features like change tracking or query generation.

Comment: Lately though I had to process invoice Excel files from dozens of partners that won't even produce the same Excel format twice, much less use a common format. Never mind headers, footers, total rows, extra columns with notes etc. At this point I used Python and Pandas to just load each file in memory and start cleaning up, eg dropping rows with too many empty fields etc. Sure, it's 10 times slower at runtime, but the break/fix/repeat cycle required by the ton of disparate files is 1000 times worse.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The part of reading the excel file is not related with EFCore. I need to access the database only while I am validating each row. Rows represent shipping orders of a courier company so I have to validate against proper addresses (I have zipcode entries in my database for instance), I have remote areas where certain courier services do not apply, I have smart points, etc. There is a very complex validation process for each row. So I need to access the database in a lookup way (eg "Is the service requested by the client supported in that destination?" etc).

Comment: So I would either hit the database many times for each row, or (that is what I did in the end) load all zipcodes, stations, remote areas etc tables in memory as readonly dictionaries, and use them instead.

Comment: Now imagine doing that for air tickets, with multimillion-row lookup tables. The specifics matter *a lot*. You don't need an ORM for lookup queries, but you *do* want to load as little as possible. Dapper is more than enough for this as there's no change tracking. Executing one query per row is too expensive though, so you either need to cache the lookup data or *not* use lookups in memory. It depends on the actual data sizes. It may be better to load the data into a staging table and LEFT JOIN with big lookup tables.

Comment: Please add the missing information in the question itself. There are a *lot* of possible techniques. Zip codes are so few for example you can just load them in memory, either in a dictionary or cache. Unless you need to handle international zip codes. How much data are you processing each time? Is the dataflow used only for a single request at a time (not very useful), or is it a BackgroundService that handles all requests (more useful)?